# How to reload page when a button is clicked?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, reload

I need to refresh current page when confirm button is clicked. I am trying to find the answer on the internet, but with little or no success at all. It would be nice if there was a way to update it from front-end (JSF), not from backing bean, but, I will take both answers as solutions.

My command button looks like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="deleteButton" styleClass="simpleButtonRed"
        value="#{msg['common.delete']}"
        execute="@this" render="@none" limitRender="true" >
        <adn:confirm
            id="confirmButtonas"    
            message="#{msg['common.delete.confirm']}"
            confirmAction="#{messagesListBean.deleteMessages}"
            confirmLabel="#{msg['common.confirm']}"
            confirmBtnStyleClass="mainButtonGreen"
            confirmImmediate="true" 
            confirmRender="errorMessageOuterPanel" 
            onConfirmComplete="if(#{!messagesListBean.operationCompleted}) {
                               #{rich:component('errorPanel')}.show();}"/>
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715047/how-to-reload-a-page-using-javascript)

```
location.reload();
```

---

Or you can redirect to same `URI` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486744/3850595).

First change commandButton to call bean method:

```
onConfirmComplete="#{messagesListBean.reload}"
```

And in the bean:

```
public void reload() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(((HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest()).getRequestURI());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `render` attribute of `a4j:commandButton` for this purpose.
Example:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="buttonName"
    action="#{bean.action}"
    render="someForm" />
```

In your code change `render="@none"` to `render="@form"` or `render="@all"`.