# Primefaces - update @all from backing bean

Tags: java, primefaces, updates

I am sure that this is really stupid question but I couldn't find any examples.

I would like to update a whole page from the backing bean.
I already managed to update the content of a dialog by using

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("dialog-form-id");`

Is there anything like `[...].update("@all")` or do I really need to pass the method the whole form id list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reload the same page from a managedBean in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483214/how-can-i-reload-the-same-page-from-a-managedbean-in-jsf)

Comment: I'm talking about an update, I don't want the page to be refreshed

Comment: Why you don't want to have the page refreshed? Normally you should avoid using @all and refresh the page instead.

Comment: Because otherwise I'll lose stuff that has been done but not saved.
I need an update to show the user the changes he just did before he saves them.
Plus, I can't have the visual clue of a page refreshing that sometimes happens.

Comment: Then you need to  wrap everything you want to update in a component which is updatable e.q. h:panelGroup. Then you're able update the panelGroup from your bean and everything inside the panelGroup is updated too. If there's a form which contains the whole page you could also update the form by its id, then you won't need a panelGroup.